# How can i get a metric from a specific version in sonarqube using the webservice api

Tags: sonarqube

For my release automation i'm creating a document generator that includes the current measurements from sonarqube. In this document i would like to report the differences between several versions of the code.
I managed to get the list of versions without any problem using
    http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/events?resource=org.codehaus.sonar:sonar&categories=Version
And i also managed to get a measurement of the current code state using
    http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?resource=org.codehaus.sonar:sonar&metrics=ncloc

Can anybody help me in how to get the `ncloc` of an older version, say version '4.0'?

Answer (score 1):

The Web Service does not allow to query this information.

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution is roundabout but you could get the data you desire based on the version.

Proposed solution:

1. Get the version-specific details from the API.
   http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/events?resource=org.codehaus.sonar:sonar&categories=Version&format=json

   The response would be something like:

   ```
   [{"id":"23761","rk":"helloworld","n":"1.1","c":"Version","dt":"2017-07-19T20:28:54-0500"},
   {"id":"23731","rk":"helloworld","n":"1.0","c":"Version","dt":"2017-07-18T14:51:20-0500"},
   {"id":"5107","rk":"helloworld","n":"1","c":"Version","dt":"2015-12-07T11:37:44-0600"}]
   ```

   The "dt" value specifies the point of time where the Version is released.
2. Parse the JSON and get the `dt` values. Find the minimum and maximum date values from the obtained `dt` values.
3. Use the time machine API to query out the metrics you need using the API
   http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/timemachine?resource=helloworld&metrics=coverage,ncloc&rfomDateTime=(min_dt_value)&toDateTime=(max_dt_value)

   You will get all the metrics between the timestamps.
4. Compare our version-specific `dt` values against the one obtained from the above response and thus get the version specific metric values.